# regex for line of string

Tags: python, regex

Hi I try to extract some information from a few lines in python with a regular expression. What I have now is: `([a-zA-Z()]+\S\S)`
My lines are:

```
Butter 100mg x 12
Butter Organic Jelly 100mg x 7
Butter Soft 100mg x 12
3.5g Organic White Loofi
10g Bubblegum
10 x TST Butter 200yg Hofmann
100 x 10mg Jelly (Test)
```

With the regex above I get the strings Butter, Butter, Organic, Jelly, Butter, Soft, Organic, White, Loofi, Bubblegum, TST, Butter, Jelly, (Test). But I want the string from every line like: Butter, Butter Organic Jelly, Butter Soft, etc. Not seperated from each other. What do I do wrong?

Comment: Something like [`[a-zA-Z()]+\S\S(?:\s+[a-zA-Z()]+\S\S)*`](https://regex101.com/r/mM7uF0/1)? I doubt so, but please check.

Comment: You want the result as one string without any numbers or multipliers?

Comment: [Another demo](https://ideone.com/ULj9Ej) - any better?

Comment: I thought so too but this doesn't work for me. And yes I want the result as one string. For example I want "Butter Organic Jelly" as one string. The regex that I wrote seperates all the words.

Comment: can you please attach the code you've written so as to capture the text?

Comment: @Array: Splitting with a newline should not be that hard. See [my former updated demo](https://ideone.com/ULj9Ej).

Comment: [Another demo](https://ideone.com/71hKNv)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This regex works for you particular cases: `([A-Z][a-z][A-Za-z()\s]+[a-z)])`

What it says is, find a string where:

- the first character is an uppercase char (used to get rid of `mg`)
- the second a lowercase char (it is used to reject `TST Butter` and only keep `Butter` and not `TST`), then
- then 0 or more of uppercase, lowercase, parentheses or whitespace
- the last character is a closing parenthesis or a lowercase char.

This gives me the following matches:

- Butter
- Butter Organic Jelly
- Butter Soft
- Organic White Loofi
- Bubblegum
- Butter
- Hofmann
- Jelly (Test)

Comment: Thx, it was really helpful.

Comment: What if I want the TST too? Can I remove the lovercase char?

Comment: Just remove the second [] yes

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following regex

```
((?:(?:[a-zA-Z\(\)]{3,})+[ ]?)+)
```

It finds words bigger than three that has no digits in them, separated by whitespace characters.

```
import re

recipe = """
Butter 100mg x 12
Butter Organic Jelly 100mg x 7
Butter Soft 100mg x 12
3.5g Organic White Loofi
10g Bubblegum
10 x TST Butter 200yg Hofmann
100 x 10mg Jelly (Test)
"""

pattern = re.compile('((?:(?:[a-zA-Z\(\)]{3,})+[ ]?)+)')
separated = pattern.findall(recipe)

print separated
>>> ['Butter ', 'Butter Organic Jelly ', 'Butter Soft ', 'Organic White Loofi', 'Bubblegum', 'TST Butter ', 'Hofmann', 'Jelly (Test)']
```